# SQL trigger calculate between column table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table `INVENTORY`

```
Create table INVENTORY(){
      INVENID int indentity,      -- inventory ID
      PRODUCTID varchar(10), --product id
      QUANTUM int,      -- quantum
      QUANTUMINPUT int, -- quantum input
      QUANTUMOUTPUT int, -- quantum output
}
```

I created trigger :

```
Create trigger trig_cal
on INVENTORY
after insert,update
as
if(UPDATE(QUANTUMINPUT))
begin
UPDATE INVENTORY set QUANTUM  = QUANTUM + QUANTUMINPUT
end
else if(UPDATE(QUANTUMOUTPUT))
begin
UPDATE INVENTORY set QUANTUM  = QUANTUM - QUANTUMOUTPUT
end
```

I tried insert `Insert into INVENTORY(PRODUCTID,QUANTUM) values('P01',100)`
then `UPDATE INVENTORY set QUANTUMOUTPUT = 1 where PRODUCTID = 'P01'`
it return `QUANTUM` = 90 . It's wrong
however, when I update `QUANTUMOUTPUT` or `QUANTUMINPUT`, calculation is wrong

Comment: What is your expected result. Please put some sample data.

Comment: I have made few changes please check the new code.

Comment: Once you create the table and trigger. Please execute the insert and update statement then see whether you get the expected result or not. for me its working fine.

Comment: This table design doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me. Are you really trying to use two columns of a table to "control" updates to another column in the same row? Also, any SQL Server trigger that doesn't reference the `inserted` and/or `deleted` tables is almost certainly broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this trigger code

```
   CREATE TABLE INVENTORY
  (
     INVENID       INT,-- inventory ID
     PRODUCTID     VARCHAR(10),--product id
     QUANTUM       INT,-- quantum
     QUANTUMINPUT  INT,-- quantum input
     QUANTUMOUTPUT INT, -- quantum output
  )

ALTER TRIGGER trig_cal
ON INVENTORY
after UPDATE
AS
    IF( UPDATE(QUANTUMINPUT) )
      BEGIN
          UPDATE INV
          SET    INV.QUANTUM = INS.QUANTUM + INS.QUANTUMINPUT
          FROM   INVENTORY INV
                 JOIN INSERTED INS
                   ON ISNULL(INS.INVENID, 0) = ISNULL(INV.INVENID, 0)
                      AND ISNULL(INS.PRODUCTID, 0) = ISNULL(INV.PRODUCTID, 0)
      END
    ELSE IF( UPDATE(QUANTUMOUTPUT) )
      BEGIN
          UPDATE INV
          SET    INV.QUANTUM = INS.QUANTUM - INS.QUANTUMOUTPUT
          FROM   INVENTORY INV
                 JOIN INSERTED INS
                   ON ISNULL(INS.INVENID, 0) = ISNULL(INV.INVENID, 0)
                      AND ISNULL(INS.PRODUCTID, 0) = ISNULL(INV.PRODUCTID, 0)
      END

    INSERT INTO INVENTORY
                (PRODUCTID,
                 QUANTUM)
    VALUES     ('P01',
                100)

    UPDATE INVENTORY
    SET    QUANTUMOUTPUT = 1
    WHERE  PRODUCTID = 'P01'

    UPDATE INVENTORY
    SET    QUANTUMINPUT = 1
    WHERE  PRODUCTID = 'P01'
```